# Athena Select Query to Covert UTC timestamp to Required zone timestamp format

Tags: python, sql, python-2.7, amazon-athena

I tried below query in Athena getting output with extra string "America/New_York", not in the expected format, need to remove the extra string from the value using athena query

Query:

```
SELECT execution_date, execution_date AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York' as us,AT_TIMEZONE(execution_date, 'America/New_York') as us2 FROM "db"."table" limit 3;
```

Output of above query:

```
execution_date                  us                                              us2 
2019-12-04 13:50:47.000 2019-12-04 08:50:47.000 America/New_York    2019-12-04 08:50:47.000 America/New_York
```

expected output:

```
execution_date                  us                                              us2 
2019-12-04 13:50:47.000   2019-12-04 08:50:47.000                       2019-12-04 08:50:47.000
```

if any more information required please let me know.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes i'm trying this in Amazon Athena service,

Comment: I have removed the MySQL Tag as it is that which is confusing people

Answer (score 1):

I tried this, and it works but it gives the name of the region in the TIMESTAMP, which might or might not be what you're looking for.

```
SELECT AT_TIMEZONE(DATE_PARSE(timestamp,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'),'America/Chicago') FROM table_name;
```

The output is like `2020-05-07 17:09:19.000 America/Chicago`, with the TIMESTAMP adjusted according to the timezone, and then the timezone name in the end.

I think this is how Athena represents timestamp with timezone.

**Edit**: If the column is already of the type `TIMESTAMP` (and not `VARCHAR`), then just use `AT_TIMEZONE(column_name,'America/Chicago')`

Comment: Getting below issue :
SYNTAX_ERROR: line 1:89: Unexpected parameters (timestamp, varchar(17)) for function date_parse. Expected: date_parse(varchar(x), varchar(y))

Comment: @Ahito It looks like your column type is already of type `TIMESTAMP` . In this case, simply run 
SELECT AT_TIMEZONE(column_name,'America/Chicago') FROM table_name;

Comment: i used the same in the above query for 3rd field(us2) still extra string is getting appended to it. wants to ignore extra string.

Comment: I think that's how the `TIMESTAMP` with `TIMEZONE` is meant to be displayed in Athena.  
But if you still want to remove the string,`select replace(column_name,'America/Chicago','') as timestamp_col from table_name` 

Please consider upvoting and marking the answer as accepted as it answers your question :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use this, CONVERT_TZ help you to change date to another time zone

MYSQL SERVER 8:

```
CONVERT_TZ(timeperiod, 'UTC', 'Asia/Tehran')
```

or

```
WHERE CONVERT_TZ(timeperiod, 'UTC', '{$this->timezone}') 
NOT BETWEEN 
{$timeperiods['today_start']} AND {$timeperiods['today_end']}
```

Comment: Getting below Error-
SYNTAX_ERROR: line 1:77: Function convert_tz not registered in athena

Comment: look link at this you must update your mysql to version 8. , https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz

Comment: He's asking for Athena, not MySQL. and seems like he had put the mysql tag